# Parse error in php validation

Tags: php, mysql, compiler-errors

ive been trying get this code working for a long time now and I am still getting the same error.
any help would be great.

**error code**

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in /home/ob219/public_html/membership/classes/Validate.php on line 38
```

**code**

```
<?php
class Validate {
private $_passed = false,
        $_errors = array(),
        $_db = null;

public function __construct() {
    $this->_db = DB::getInstance();
}

public function check($source, $items = array()) {
    foreach($items as $item => $rules) {
        foreach($rules as $rule => $rule_value) {

            $value = trim($source[$item]);
            $item = escape($item);

            if($rule == 'required' && empty($value)) {
                $this->addError("{$item} is required");
            } else if(!empty($value)) {
                switch($rule) {
                    case 'min':
                        if(strlen($value) < $rule_value) {
                            $this->addError("{$item} must be a minimum of {$rule_value} characters.");
                        }
                    break;
                    case 'max':
                        if(strlen($value) > $rule_value) {
                            $this->addError("{$item} must be a maximum of {$rule_value} characters.");
                        }
                    break;
                    case 'matches':
                        if($value != $source [$rule_value]) {
                            $this->addError("{$rule_value} must match {$item}");
                        }
                    break;
                    case 'unique':
                        $check = $this->_db->get($rule_value, array($item, '=', $value);
                            if($check->count()) {
                                $this->addError("{$item} already exists.");
                            }
                    break;


                }

            }

        }
    }

    if(empty($this->_errors)) {
        $this->_passed = true;
    }

    return $this;
}

private function addError($error) {
    $this->_errors[] = $error;
}

public function errors() {
    return $this->_errors;
}

public function passed() {
    return $this->_passed;
}
}
```

Comment: well, which is line 38?

Comment: @Jessica im using sublime text 2, can you recommend a better one?

Comment: PHPStorm, Eclipse, Zend Studio, Visual Studio, the sky is the limit. All that I've named are better choices though.

Comment: Excellent thank you for your suggestions, I will find a new one that suits me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Forgot closing paranthesis. Change

```
$check = $this->_db->get($rule_value, array($item, '=', $value);
```

To

```
$check = $this->_db->get($rule_value, array($item, '=', $value));
```

Comment: Why use a syntax highlighting editor when you can get someone on Stack Overflow to fix it for you, right?

Comment: @tadman i normally go through my code over and over till i solve problems myself. but this one i truly could not see. its always best to get a second pair of eyes that can spot a simple error.

Comment: Or you could have simply looked at line 38 :p

Comment: @skrilled i did, and as i stated in the question i could not understand the problem in the error as it informed me that i was missing ; and in the end it was a ). im new to php so am not fantastic and sometimes i need some help so i ask politely for some help. but only after i have tried all i can to fix the error.

Comment: I feel you, I'm just saying the error was clearly on line 38. Now that you know how arrays work I hope you have learned from it.